# Getting a Caught NoReverseMatch error in django

Tags: python, html, django, url, view

I have a view called edit_order, and I have another view called client_items.

```
def edit_order(request, order_no)
    change_item = order.contact.client

def client_items(request, client_id = 0):
    client = None
    items = None
    try:
        client = models.Client.objects.get(pk = client_id)
        items = client.storageitem_set.all()
    except:
        return HttpResponse(reverse(return_clients))
    return render_to_response('items.html', {'items':items, 'client':client}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

And in my edit order template I have a template tag url.

```
<input type="button"  value="Edit items" onclick="window.location.href='{% url tiptop.views.client_items change_item.pk  %}'" />
```

This works. Now, I want to make another view which does the same but can use an order_no parameter. But for some reason *this* does not work. I have called this view test_items.

```
def test_items(request, client_id = 0, order_no=0):
    client = None
    items = None
    try:
        client = models.Client.objects.get(pk = client_id)
        items = client.storageitem_set.all()
        order = models.Order.objects.get(pk = order_no)
    except:
        return HttpResponse(reverse(return_clients))
    return render_to_response('test.html', {'items':items, 'client':client, 'order':order}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

And in my template I have changed the url to this.

```
<input type="button"  value="Edit items" onclick="window.location.href='{% url tiptop.views.test_items change_item.pk  %}'" />
```

So I get this error.

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'tiptop.views.test_items' with arguments '(17L,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

The reason why this is causing this is the order_no parameter. But I want to be able to use this parameter. Is there a way I can overcome this issue? I hope this all made sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, how are you passing the order_no parameter? And what does your urls.py look like? In your modified template you are not passing an order_no to the {% url %} tag. If your URL regexp requires both parameters (client_id and order_no) then it won't find a matching URL. You could try something like this in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('tiptop.views',
    (r'^(\d+)/(\d*)$', 'test_items'),
)
```

But in your case, it might be better to just pass the order_no as a GET parameter.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply (my internet was down). I have `(r'^search/(?P<client_id>\d+)/(?P<order_no>\d+)/test_items/$', views.test_items),`I don't see a problem.

Comment: In your regular expression, you require two parameters (\d+ means you match one or more digits). In your template code, you provide only one parameter, that's why you get the NoReverseMatch exception. Modify your code to do something like {% url tiptop.views.test_items change_item.pk order.pk %} and it will work.

Comment: Yes, it has made it worked and - ... seem to get a new error. Once I opened up an edit order form and click on the link at `{% url tiptop.views.test_items change_item.pk order.pk %}`, I get a `Caught TypeError while rendering: 'Order' object is not iterable` error.

Comment: EDIT: it is solved! changed the definition of order. Thanks for you help anyway.