# Getting another error in Django: Caught NoReverseMatch error in django

Tags: python, html, django, url, view

I seem to have another problem with passing parameters in Django. I seem to get a Caught NoReverseMatch error.

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'tiptop.views.service_order2' with arguments '('', 17L, 1)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found
```

It reaches the client_id and service_type but not the order_no. I am not so sure what is wrong but it complains of the order.pk argument.

```
#urls
(r'^quote/service_order/(?P<client_id>\d+)/(?P<order_no>\d+)/(?P<request_type>\d+)/$', views.service_order2),

#views.py
def service_order2(request, client_id = 0, order_no = 0, request_type = 1):
    # A lot of code
    order=request.session['order']
    return render_to_response('service_step1__2nd.html', {'contacts':contacts, 'addresses':addresses, 'title':title, 'service_list':service_list, 'date_type':date_type, 'address_type':address_type, 'order':order}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

This template contains the template tag link that is suppose to go to service_step1__2.html template

```
<input type="submit" value="Request Delivery" onclick="change_action('{% url tiptop.views.service_order2 order.pk client.pk 1 %}')"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `order` object does not have a `pk` value, for whatever reason - presumably it's a new unsaved instance. So it's passing an empty string as the first parameter to the URL, and is failing to match your `service_order2` url which expects a number in that position.

Comment: The only problem is that it worked before. I had a similar problem before again with order.pk, but I resolved it because order.pk was missing in my html template tag. see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066337/getting-a-caught-noreversematch-error-in-django]

Comment: Clearly `order.pk` is not returning a value. Fix that issue first. You'd run into a second problem once you fix that since your view is expecting client.pk then order.pk